# What is wrong? Why is it giving me unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java

What is wrong? Why is it giving me "unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException"? This is an exercise for a book I'm learning from and I just can't figure out what is wrong, it looks exactly like and example they provided. This file is in the same folder.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Mine
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Scanner inFile = 
          new Scanner(new FileReader("Ch3_Ex7Data.txt"));
      PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Ch3_Ex7Output.dat");

      String lastName;
      lastName = inFile.next();
      System.out.println(lastName);
      inFile.close();
      outFile.close();
    }
}
```

[image: Files]

Comment: In the same folder as what?

Comment: It isn't finding the file you are trying to read.  Where is the file in relation to your compiled class file?

Comment: More importantly, where is the file in relation to your current directory at the time you execute the program?

Comment: The file is in the same place as the compiled class file so I didn't think I needed to add a path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileNotFoundException is a checked exception. You have to try/catch for it. It doesn't matter whether the file exists or not. FileNotFoundException extends IOException so you only need to catch IOException. This should compile:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Mine
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner inFile = null;
        PrintWriter outFile = null;
        try {
            try {
                inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Ch3_Ex7Data.txt"));
                outFile = new PrintWriter("Ch3_Ex7Output.dat");

                String lastName;
                lastName = inFile.next();
                System.out.println(lastName);
            } finally {
                if(inFile != null)
                    inFile.close();
                if(outFile != null)
                    outFile.close();
            }
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure what the try concept is, I haven't learned that yet, but it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Basically if the file isn't found the constructor will throw this exception. try/catch means control flow will jump out and to the catch block if it does. (BTW the thing I showed with try...finally...close isn't totally necessary but a best practice. Java 7+ also has [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to replace the idiom.) It's possible the exception will be thrown at run time in which case what @peeskillet has suggested may be of some help. Relative directories are finicky.

Answer (score 1):

`FileNotFoundException` means, well... then file can't be found.

Make sure the `"Ch3_Ex7Data.txt"` file is a direct child of the project root directory. Reading a file, that's where your IDE will first search, when you're just using *this* ("Ch3_Ex7Data.txt") relative path.

```
ProjectRoot
         Ch3_Ex7Data.txt
         src
```

Note: in the future, you will learn that is not the best solution for production/deployment purposes, when the file is t become an embedded resources, but the above should work for you, until you delve deeper towards the production stage.

---

**UPDATE** to OP comment

> " And should I get in the habit of the other method now? and if so what does that look like"

You'll want to learn it in the future, but you will first need to learn about `InputStreams`. So it may be a but premature. But if you wan't to learn more, just search "Reading a text file from a jar". You'll find answers that'll look like this

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Ch3_Ex7Data.txt");
```

Where you file would now have to be located in the class path, so your file structure would instead change from the above structure to *this* below

```
ProjectRoot
          src
             Ch3_Ex7Data.txt
```

Comment: Where should I add that code. And should I get in the habit of the other method now? and if so what does that look like? Thanks

Comment: all the files are in the same folder

Comment: Yes but where are they, relative to your project root directory? That's what's important.

Comment: See picture I just added

Comment: Where is your `src`? is in `Excr7`. Is `Excr7` the actual project folder or a package?

Comment: Sorry a few files got cut off,see new picture.I have been doing all my files in blueJ and it compiles and runs the programs in the application, except for it won't compile because it keeps throwing this area so I can't export it.